# How to manage state in EJBClientInterceptor

Tags: java, wildfly, ejb-3.0, interceptor

**What is the proper way to handle state in `org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInterceptor`**?

In Wildfly 12 I would like to create an adapter for our general interceptor chains.
Let's simplify the problem to create simple duration logging EJB client interceptor.
Unfortunately the `EJBClientInterceptor` 2-method design is strange:

```
public interface EJBClientInterceptor {

    /**
     * Handle the invocation.  Implementations may short-circuit the invocation by throwing an exception.  This method
     * should process any per-interceptor state and call {@link EJBClientInvocationContext#sendRequest()}.
     *
     * @param context the invocation context
     * @throws Exception if an invocation error occurs
     */
    void handleInvocation(EJBClientInvocationContext context) throws Exception;

    /**
     * Handle the invocation result.  The implementation should generally call {@link EJBClientInvocationContext#getResult()}
     * immediately and perform any post-invocation cleanup task in a finally block.
     *
     * @param context the invocation context
     * @return the invocation result, if any
     * @throws Exception if an invocation error occurred
     */
    Object handleInvocationResult(EJBClientInvocationContext context) throws Exception;
}
```

The problem is that since the interceptor is divided into 2 methods, you have to transfer the state from "before" part (`handleInvocation`) into "after" part (`handleInvocationResult`).

#### Flow overview

```
    @Override
    public void handleInvocation(EJBClientInvocationContext ejbClientInvocationContext) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("handleInvocation - before sendRequest");
        ejbClientInvocationContext.sendRequest();
        System.out.println("handleInvocation - after sendRequest");
    }

    @Override
    public Object handleInvocationResult(EJBClientInvocationContext ejbClientInvocationContext) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("handleInvocationResult - before getResult");
        try {
            return ejbClientInvocationContext.getResult();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("handleInvocationResult - after getResult");
        }
    }
```

Results in this output

```
client_1  | 16:50:24,575 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) handleInvocation - before sendRequest
client_1  | 16:50:24,718 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) handleInvocation - after sendRequest
server_1  | 16:50:25,737 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Doing work at EJB server
client_1  | 16:50:25,771 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) handleInvocationResult - before getResult
client_1  | 16:50:25,795 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) handleInvocationResult - after getResult
```

#### Bad solution #1 - instance fields

Another problem is that the interceptor instance is singleton and is reused for all calls. So you can not use fields in the interceptor like this

```
public class DurationLogging1ClientInterceptor implements EJBClientInterceptor {

    private long startTime;

    @Override
    public void handleInvocation(EJBClientInvocationContext ejbClientInvocationContext) throws Exception {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ejbClientInvocationContext.sendRequest();
    }

    @Override
    public Object handleInvocationResult(EJBClientInvocationContext ejbClientInvocationContext) throws Exception {
        try {
            return ejbClientInvocationContext.getResult();
        } finally {
            long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            System.out.println("Call took " + duration + "ms");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Bad solution #2 - ThreadLocal

Another way is to use `ThreadLocal`:

```
public class DurationLogging2ClientInterceptor implements EJBClientInterceptor {

    private final ThreadLocal<Long> startTimeTL = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @Override
    public void handleInvocation(EJBClientInvocationContext ejbClientInvocationContext) throws Exception {
        startTimeTL.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
        ejbClientInvocationContext.sendRequest();
    }

    @Override
    public Object handleInvocationResult(EJBClientInvocationContext ejbClientInvocationContext) throws Exception {
        try {
            return ejbClientInvocationContext.getResult();
        } finally {
            long startTime = startTimeTL.get();
            long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            System.out.println("Call took " + duration + "ms");
        }
    }
}
```

But I am not sure if the method `handleInvocationResult` is guaranteed to be invoked in the same thread as `handleInvocation`. And even if it is, I do not like the usage of `ThreadLocal`.

#### Bad solution #3 - Use `contextData` map

Another way is to transfer state through the `EJBClientInvocationContext` parameter, maybe using the `getContextData()` property:

```
public class DurationLogging3ClientInterceptor implements EJBClientInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void handleInvocation(EJBClientInvocationContext ejbClientInvocationContext) throws Exception {
        ejbClientInvocationContext.getContextData().put("startTime", System.currentTimeMillis());
        ejbClientInvocationContext.sendRequest();
    }

    @Override
    public Object handleInvocationResult(EJBClientInvocationContext ejbClientInvocationContext) throws Exception {
        try {
            return ejbClientInvocationContext.getResult();
        } finally {
            long startTime = (Long) ejbClientInvocationContext.getContextData().get("startTime");
            long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            System.out.println("Call took " + duration + "ms");
        }
    }
}
```

But this `contextData` map is serialized and sent to EJB server, which is something I do not want to.

#### Previous Jboss Interceptor design

In previous Jboss versions there was much easier `org.jboss.aop.advice.Interceptor` design that solved all these problems:

```
public interface Interceptor {
    String getName();

    Object invoke(Invocation invocation) throws Throwable;
}
```

The duration logging interceptor could be written as this

```
public class DurationLogging4ClientInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return getClass().getName();
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Invocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        try {
            return invocation.invokeNext();
        } finally {
            long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            System.out.println("Call took " + duration + "ms");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Dockerized demo project to play with

I have created a demo project with 2 Wildfly instances inside `docker-compose`. One instance acts as an ejb-client and another one as an ejb-server. There are multiple EJB call scenario demonstrations with interceptors.

https://github.com/petr-ujezdsky/w2w

Comment: Were you able to clarify if `handleInvocation` and `handleInvocationResult` are indeed going to be in the same thread?  I would think they would need to be in order for the logic wrapping the EJB calls to succeed, but have not found documentation indicating one way or the other.  Were you able to identify with certainty that they are the same thread?

Answer (score 0):

I think solution 3 is not so bad, and can be improved with some trick.

If you do not want to send the actual object thru the wire, maybe you can put the "hash" of your actual object into the contextdata (I would assume that you can use Objects.hashcode() for this purpose).

At the same time, you save your object keyed with this unique hash in a static LRUMap field (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/LRUMap.html).

This way when you get back the control in the second method you can lookup what you've saved into your static Map based on its hash.

Comment: I guess you can.. But then the static-storage has to be synchronized against **all** server calls. You also have to be sure you properly remove the state from the map to prevent memory leak. This storage should also exist in every given interceptor. You should also create new object to describe the types the state should have, not so pretty :(

Comment: @PetrÚjezdskýRegarding the memory leak: LRUMap takes care of removing "old" data; it is a last recently used map, which will throw out (so release) not used objects.

Comment: @PetrÚjezdský
1. Regarding the memory leak: LRUMap takes care of removing "old" data; it is a last recently used map, which will throw out (so release) not used objects. You can also help it by manual removing in handle*result().
2. About sync: I've wanted to suggest that `Objects.hashcode(o)` should be used as the key in the LRUmap; AFAIK `Objects.hashcode()` returns the memory address of the given object, so there can't be a data race on the Map (assuming that the saved object is not finalized during the server call). I've edited my answer, Object**s**.hashcode()...